# jhipster login page not showing up for 0auth 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jhipster

In [Jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) 5.0.1 with [0auth2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) selected, I get an error page when I try when I click the login button. The register button in the drop down doesn't showup. It works fine with JWT authentication which makes me think that there's another step to setup 0auth2.0 authentication. Has anyone set this up before?

My project is also getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[50], headers={contentType=application/json, id=d9a00faa-0923-c5ba-149b-0439cbe91291, timestamp=1530014266697}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:138)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
```

but I believe it's unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to start Keycloak before you'll be able to login to it.

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/keycloak.yml up
```

Or you can signup for an [Okta developer account](https://developer.okta.com) and configure your settings to use it instead. See [JHipster's security documentation](https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#-oauth2-and-openid-connect) for more information.